# Using sudo to install maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, permissions, root, mahout

I've asked a couple of questions already trying to get around this. I've tried not using maven at all, but would like to figure out why it hasn't worked for me in the first place. All the guides I see online that detail how to install maven projects just say to check out the code, go to the directory you want and

```
mvn install
```

and it should just work. However, I always have to use

```
sudo mvn install
```

As a result, my builds are successful (installing mahout and hadoop) but because the installation was done by root, a normal instance of eclipse can't access the files because it does not have root permissions. I must be doing something wrong since these kinds of problems don't seem to be mentioned by others explaining how to do maven installs. Launching eclipse as root with

```
sudo eclipse
```

does solve this problem, but people are forever telling me it's a bad idea to anything as root.

Here's an example of a guide I looked at 
http://harish11g.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/configuring-mahout-clustering-hadoop.html

What have I missed?

Comment: Why you have to use `sudo`?

Comment: I personally prefer always use the usergroup rather than root!

Comment: What OS / version were you running?  I'm seeing similar issues on Mac OS X / Sierra.  Also, this question may be duplicating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940540/maven-bash-mvn-permission-denied

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of these projects builds. Typically, however, `mvn install` is not run with elevated privileges because all it does is build the projects and put the output artifacts in `~/.m2/repository/`. This allows the artifacts to be referenced as dependencies by other maven projects you want to build locally. This is useful if you need to do development against unreleased code.

`mvn install` is not analogous to `make install` in that the latter will usually install binaries on system paths, where as the former installs binaries in your home directory (specifically `~/.m2/repository/` as mentioned above.