# maven: bash mvn permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, maven, centos

This is what I'm seeing:

```
mvn
bash: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn: Permission denied
```

my bash file:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export JAVA_HOME

HADOOP_HOME=/usr/share/491s14/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin   
export PATH

export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

ls command:

```
ls -l /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5806 Feb 21 11:33 /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn
```

file command:

```
file /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn
/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn: POSIX shell script text executable
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn` and `file /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn`?

Comment: edited the question with those in there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your permission shows that you can't execute that file. Modify permissions for that file. If you want all the users in the machine should be able to execute that file, then do this :

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn
```

Comment: chmod 777 didn't work for me, why? And your solution worked bang on

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn` does not have the execute permission. This should be able to fix it:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn
```

Answer (score 3):

`sudo chmod 777 <mvn location>` fixed it.  Man I suck at linux :P

Comment: So does everyone!

Comment: this is still a valid answer but I consider is very bad since 777 is an open permissions for all, this could cause a security issue

Comment: I used 744 to give execute permissions only to the file owner, however I am wondering a few things: this file was in source control (inherited project) and should it be provided by source control or generated by vscode / specified in settings.json?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `chmod +x <your-mvnw-file>`. It does work.