# MVN Permission denied on Mac

Tags: java, macos, maven

When I try to run test locally I get the error: FAIL: Compilation failed. Then it says "*/bin/sh: /Users/local/.config/tmc/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/mvn: Permission denied*"

I am able to submit and run the exercises. How can I rectify this issue? Also if wondering, I am using a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. 
type this into your terminal:
*MAKE SURE TO PUT YOUR USERNAME*

chmod +x /Users/**INSERT USERNAME**/.config/tmc/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/mvn

Answer (score 2):

Try if doing a `chmod +x mvnw` and then committing your change fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have permission to access it.

Check this answer out: [maven: bash mvn permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940540/maven-bash-mvn-permission-denied/21940766)

It shows you how you can change the permission of the file.

Comment: So it’s a dupe?

Comment: Pretty much, just the directories are different, that's all @DaveNewton